# How to delete obsolete JSFiddle versions?

Tags: jsfiddle, version-control

Can anyone tell me how I delete obsolete JSFiddle versions, but keep the base version?

Comment: Check http://jsfiddle.net/user/dashboard/ ... its list ur source ur option to delete (easy). I know a more 6 years ago kkkk

Answer (score 10):

You want to reset the code to base at the version you're editing. To do this you simply set the current version as the base version with the "Set as base" button shown below:

[image: Set as base]

Comment: Will this really delete previous versions, making them inaccessible to anyone with a link to one of those versions? I don't want that to happen to any of my documents on jsfiddle. :(

Comment: @AndersonGreen No, the old revisions are all still there. Just suffix the URL with `/0/`, `/1/`, `/2/`, . . .  Then apparently the "base" revision (with no suffix) can be set to any of these.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a new Fork, which essentially does what you want by creating a new jsfiddle from the current revision, though you'll get a new URL.

[image: jsfiddle's Fork Button]

Otherwise I do not believe there's any method to remove any specific revision or to clean up the revision history of a fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Even though it is not possible to remove specific version if you need to delete all the older versions I think the workaround is to create a **Fork** from the last version and **Set as base** that version and then delete the old one (As jsfiddle now provide a feature to delete a fiddle with all the versions)

Answer (score 0):

If need you can delete one (or all) of yours repositories clicking on the G stretched out. After go to the name of the Fiddle you want to delete a gear appears click on it and then the on the pop-up clic Delete fiddle. That's all.