# Is there a direct link to the latest revision in JSFiddle?

Tags: links, jsfiddle

I have three revisions of my fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/journeymanmw/9xLtH/3/) and I’m constantly updating it. I want to have a reference to the latest available revision so I don’t have to update the revision number in the URL every time I navigate to it.

Is it possible?

Comment: Is there some reason http://jsfiddle.net/journeymanmw/9xLtH/ doesn't work?

Comment: it show the base revision (the very first, not the latest)

Comment: That would be good information to add to your question.

Comment: it is easily visible if you compare them :)

Comment: check http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/12033/how-to-delete-obsolete-jsfiddle-versions ("Set as Base")

Comment: @Nicolas78 well, it might be of use as emergency workaround, since it resets the history, thanks

Comment: Stas, it doesn't erase the history, at least not any more. All revisions are still available with suffixes `/0/`, `/1/`, `/2/`, . . .  @Nicolas78 really does have the answer to this question with the ("Set as Base") button -- AS LONG AS you passed around the URL without any version suffix in the first place. That can be "set" to any revision later.  Example: I set http://jsfiddle.net/BobStein/ty640uva/ to http://jsfiddle.net/BobStein/ty640uva/2/

Answer (score 3):

Adding /latest/ to the end of the URL seems to work.

Comment: No authoritative answer, but it does appear that any text selects the latest version, so my reply may not be that robust.

Comment: Doesn't work (anymore). Appending any text (including `/latest/`) selects the base version, not the latest revision.

Comment: Works again.  [`/latest`](http://jsfiddle.net/journeymanmw/9xLtH/latest) and [`/latest/`](http://jsfiddle.net/journeymanmw/9xLtH/latest/) do what they say, [`/othertext/`](http://jsfiddle.net/journeymanmw/9xLtH/othertext/) gives error 404.

Comment: The `/latest` trick does not work for me as of June 2022.

Comment: The `/latest/` trick probably doesn't work – especially for public fiddles not saved by registered users – due to _security concerns_. Imagine if you create a fiddle and publish it, then I go in and edit it so that the "latest" version attacks the user in some way... or attacks someone _else_? Not cool if `/latest/` always gives the most-recently-saved version. The *set as base* capability makes the most sense, but can only be safely used by registered users.

Comment: Is not working in 2023, it shows the first change.

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% fit with your demand but nearly!

When you log into *JsFiddle*, at the *top menu bar*, you'll get a **Set as Base button**, which will make the revision you're working on the base version.

And then use your base JSFiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/journeymanmw/9xLtH/

Comment: Someone down voted for no reason ??

Comment: Good answer. (Here’s the help entry for this feature: https://docs.jsfiddle.net/getting-started#setting-fiddle-as-base-version> )